# Dynamic target in make

Tags: makefile

I am a newbie with make, and I'm trying to use it to deploy some javascript files. I have been struggling with the following problem for quite a while with no success.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
helpers/
    foo/
        foo.js
        test/
            test1.js
            test2.js
            ...
    bar/
        bar.js
        test/
            test1.js
            test2.js
            ...
    other helpers...
distrib/
    files ready for distribution
other stuff...
```

My makefile should build, among other things, the helpers. For each helper `foo` I want to produce, under distrib, the following files: `foo-version.js`, `foo-version-uncommented.js`, `foo-version-packed.js` and `foo-version-tests.zip`. The first three are obtained by foo.js, respectively as a copy, by stripping the comments and by running a javascript minifier. I already have commands to perform these tasks.

The version number should be read in the comments of the file itself, which I can easily do with

```
def version
    $(shell cat $1 | grep @version | sed -e"s/.*version *//")
endef
```

My problem is that targets like `foo-version.js` are dynamic, since they depend on the version number, which is read while running make. I have tried to use patterns, but I have failed to make this work. The problem is that something like this will not work

```
helpers := foo bar
helpers: $(helpers)
$(helpers): %: $(call version, %)
```

because the second % is not expanded in the macro call, but it is used literally.

I need to be able to do `make helpers` to build all helpers or `make foo` to build a single one. A second step would be to delete all files under `distrib` with a lower version number. Any ideas how to do this?

As a side question: would a task like this be easier with a different build tool? I'm not expert and it may be worth the pain to learn something else.

Comment: What version of Make are you using? (Try "make -v" to find out.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In GNU make, you can use the functions `call` and `eval`, usually in combination with `foreach`:

```
%-version.js: %.js
   # your recipe here
%-version-uncommented.js: %.js
   # your recipe here
%-version-packed.js: %.js
   # your recipe here
%-version-tests.zip: %.js
   # your recipe here

versions_sfxs := .js -uncommented.js -packed.js -tests.zip
helpers := $(shell ls $(HELPERSDIR))

define JS_template

helpers: $(1)-version$(2)

endef

$(foreach h, $(helpers), \
  $(foreach sfx, $(versions_sfxs), \
    $(eval $(call JS_template,$(h),$(sfx)) \
  ) \
)
```

This code is untested but it gives the general idea.  Expect to spend an afternoon debugging your use of spaces, tabs, dollar signs and backslashes, just like in shell scripts.  [Search Stack Overflow for `make` `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[make]%20eval) or something for more details and pointers.

Comment: The comment about spending an afternoon is particularly depressing... :-(

Answer (score -5):

At the end I decided to write my own build tool [PHPmake](http://projects.andreaferretti.it/phpmake). It has a syntax reminiscent of standard makefiles, but it is already more powerful than standard make, and it is easily extensible as the makefiles themselves are written in plain PHP.

No more debugging spaces, tabs and dollar signs! :-)